# Github CI/CD pipeline crashes with webpack

Tags: github, webpack, continuous-integration, github-pages, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to learn how CI/CD pipelines work.

I decided to use it with my portfolio page which should re-run itself on every push.

Here is my yaml config:

```
name: Build Bundle for Github Pages
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - source

env:
  NODE_ENV: production
  PUBLIC_URL: http://crrmacarse.github.io/
  GA_TRACKING_CODE: ${{ secrets.GA_TRACKING_CODE }}
  FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
      with:
        persist-credentials: false

    - name: Build
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run prod:pipeline
        npm run sitemap
        cp dist/index.html dist/404.html
        cp google21029c74dc702d92.html dist/
        cp robots.txt dist/

    - name: Deploy
      uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@releases/v3
      with:
        ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        BRANCH: source
        FOLDER: dist
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Source code for the webpack config:
https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/blob/source/compiler/production.pipeline.js

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66800270/webpack-fails-on-gitlab-ci-cd-without-error-after-including-kepler-gl

Answer (score 2):

If the error message is `cannot find module 'html-webpack-plugin'`, you could try, for testing, to install it.
See [`survivejs/webpack-book` issue 100](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-book/issues/100) as an example:

> The solution was to run `npm i html-webpack-plugin --save-dev` before building with webpack

The OP has fixed the GitHub Action workflow with [`crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io` commit 8a4397b](https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/commit/8a4397b0cd91e354bf25406b111629c0ae978fe4)

```
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.0.0

    - name: Use node 12
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org

    - name: install
      run: npm install
    - name: lint
      run: npm run sitemap
    - name: build
      run: npm run prod
    - name: copy
      run: npm run copy
```

*Then* the module html-webpack-plugin is properly installed and available, as seen in this [Actions CI run](https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/runs/411093011).

Comment: Hi, i'm actually using github's pipelines that rebuilds upon push on a specific branch. Should the npm install inside the yaml config would do right?

Comment: @crrmacarse I would still add a step for testing out a `npm i`, just to see if that helps.

Comment: hi @vonC, where exactly should i do that? because there is already an npm install inside the .yaml config

Comment: @crrmacarse I see, and I agree. Just for testing, can you add in the yaml a `npm i html-webpack-plugin` just to see what that would return specifically for that plugin?

Comment: I did what you've instructed me with no avail. check out the pipeline here: https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/runs/410801752?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:72

Comment: @crrmacarse OK. Not sure then. All I see (for a similar issue) is https://github.com/OpenNTF/dojo-webpack-plugin#dependency-requirements.

Comment: I hope you still have spare time to my questions.. Do i need to really commit the node_modules according to this? https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-a-javascript-action#commit-and-push-your-action-to-github

Isn't npm install would do that in pipelines?

Comment: @crrmacarse " This means you must include any package dependencies required to run the JavaScript code." It seems the same principle would apply here, as illustrated by https://abelsquidhead.com/index.php/2019/09/07/writing-my-first-custom-github-action/.

Comment: Hi @vonc, It seems to work now. I just needed to set up the node environment. But there seems to be a problem in here: 
https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/actions/runs/31841989#L30 

Parse error on what exactly?

Comment: @crrmacarse "I just needed to set up the node environment": you means as in https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/commit/4057ec0392064e73374b90f858e3e50ed51d0bd4?

Comment: @crrmacarse may be on step `-run` syntax? See https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps and https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun. Maybe the extra empty lines confuse GitHub Action?

Comment: hi, i added some sort of - name prior to run and it worked!. I have another question. I really don't know why on CI prod build works while on CD it crashes? check here: https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/runs/411128525?check_suite_focus=true#step:5:19

I added some sort of babel preset iirc. to make it work with es modules. Any idea why?

Comment: @crrmacarse Great, well done! I have updated the answer to highlight your fixes. On the CD part, I feel a separate question would help to isolate that new problem.

Comment: I'm actually composing for it right now! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm install` before build your project which installs your npm library on docker where your project will be built.

Note: Don't forget to define html-webpack-plugin on packge.json file

Comment: Hi, this should be catered with the yaml config right?
https://github.com/crrmacarse/crrmacarse.github.io/blob/source/.github/workflows/_config.yml#L24